# Самая быстрая БД для статейного сайта Python Django

Tags: sql, django, база-данных, хостинг

Делаю простой сайт со статьями 1000-2000 символов + 4-10 фото.
В Django это очень простая модель - title, region, content.
Регистрация, вход, комментарии и прочее отсутствуют - только статьи по разделам, в сумме статей будет 2000-4000.
Какая база данных (а также ssd или hdd хостинг, если это играет роль) будет самой быстрой для моей цели?

Comment: Если сайт полностью статический, то тут ни Django, ни БД вообще не нужны

Comment: ну если хотите удобную админ панель + поиск или что то еще, то в принципе любая кроме SQLite. Для Django сам разработчик рекомендует PostgreSQL, для быстрого поиска можно использовать дополнительно Elasticsearch.